# Aligning 3 divs horizontally with no margin, bug in chrome only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging

I usually have no problems finding a solution to line up divs horizontally but however this only happens in google chrome.

This page here http://webdesignbird.co.uk/free-quote/ that iv'e just started working on has the issue, the 3 pricing plans should be side-by-side with no margin or white space between them.

If you view the page on firefox it shows the way I intended, but any changes I try to make for chrome then effects firefox.

I could target chrome specifically (after iv'e researched how to) but I would rather find out why this isn't aligning as it does in firefox.  Perhaps i'm missing some code. I have only been building websites a year so my code skills are very average.

I cannot find the answer to my problem at the moment and would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I wasn't using fixed widths originally (hence the float left, display: inline-block and the float right. it never occured to me just to float them all left after I assigned a width. Thanks, that helped my headache lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't know, why it works on firefox, but it seems that you just forgot the `float:left` on the `tier-2-container`.

Edit: I got the containers confused.

Comment: float left on tier-2-container I think you meant. And yes that worked. I wasn't using fixed widths originally (hence the float left, display: inline-block and the float right. it never occured to me just to float them all left after I assigned a width. Thanks